# SQL Server : calculating percentage in Derived table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to work with 3 tables and create a derived table to get some data together that shows a percentage of completion.

The 3 tables I have that I'm working with are `Student`, `Tests` and `Results`. I'm trying to join the 3 together and create a derived table that shows the student and the progress they have made, in a percentage of tests completed.

As an example, lets assume the 3 students I want to track have all been assigned 3 tests (out of a table with hundreds) and I want to see how far along they are. If they completed all 3 tests the derived table should store the value 100%.

```
StudentID  SName
-----------------
1          Ken
2          Tom
3          Bob

TestID  TName 
----------------
11      Test 101
22      Test 102
33      Test 103

ResultsID  TestID  StudentID   Passed
--------------------------------------
  1          11      Tom          0
  2          11      Bob          1
  3          22      Bob          1
  4          33      Bob          1
```

Derived table:

```
StudentID  SName %Completed
---------------------------
1          Ken      0%
2          Tom      0%
3          Bob    100%
```

I have tried a lot of different methods and don't know which one to even show because I feel like all the attempts have been completely wrong. Any ideas? Sorry if the formatting isn't great, it's my first post here :)

Thanks!

Comment: You should show your attempts.

Comment: Wow, lot's of great solutions and suggestions. Thanks all for taking the time and helping out with this! I tried all 3 different approaches and learned something new with each one :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data, we can't see that Ken has been assigned to the 3 tests, so we must assume that all tracked students have been assigned to all tracked tests.

Here's what I would do:

1. Build a set of all combinations of tracked students and tests (`CROSS JOIN` with 2 `WHERE` conditions)
2. Determine the results using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (replace `NULL` with 0)
3. Calculate the `AVG` result (casted to a number) while I `GROUP BY` student

This can be written in a single `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT s.StudentID, s.SName, AVG(CAST(ISNULL(r.Passed, 0) as float)) AS Completed
FROM Students s CROSS JOIN Tests t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Results r ON t.TestID = r.TestID AND s.StudentID = r.StudentID
WHERE s.StudentID IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND t.TestID IN (11, 22, 33)
GROUP BY s.StudentID, s.SName
```

The formatting (as percentage) of the `Completed` value should be done in the client application.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a `join` and `group by` with a twist:

```
select s.StudentID, s.SName,
       sum(case when r.passed = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) / t.cnt as ratio
from students s left join
     results r
     on s.studentid = r.studentid cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from tests
     ) t
group by s.StudentID, s.SName, t.cnt;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I have tried your suggested query with the addition of the sum(case when a.CompletionStatus = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) / **nullif(t.cnt,0)** to prevent a divide by zero error, however the column name comes in as blank instead of as cnt for some reason.

Comment: @KenM . . . The values are numbers, so a blank can only mean `NULL`.  The `sum()` can't produce a `NULL` value and `t.cnt` isn't `NULL`.  I don't see how the results could be blank ("0", yes, but not blank).

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean the values in the column but the actual column name itself is not initializing as cnt but as (No column name). And I can't figure out why it's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

To get all possible combinations of students with the tests.
One could cross join to a sub-query of the tests the students should pass.

Then all possible combinations of student/test can be left joined to the actual results.

After that, it's a simple GROUP BY with an average.

```
select 
 stu.StudentID, 
 stu.SName, 
 concat(AVG(coalesce(res.Passed,0)*100),'%') as [%Completed]
from Students as stu
cross join (
    select TestID, TName 
    from Tests 
    where TestID in (11,22,33)
) as tst
left join Results as res on (res.StudentID = stu.StudentID and res.TestID = tst.TestID)
group by stu.StudentID, stu.SName
```

**Example snippet:**

```
-- Sample data
-- Using table variables for demonstration
declare @Students table (StudentID int identity(1,1) primary key, SName varchar(30));
insert into @Students (Sname) values 
('Ken'),
('Tom'),
('Bob'),
('Jane');
declare @Tests table (TestID int primary key, TName varchar(30));
insert into @Tests (TestID, TName) values 
(11,'Test 101'),
(22,'Test 102'),
(33,'Test 103');
declare @Results table (ResultsID int identity(1,1) primary key, TestID int, StudentID int, Passed bit);
insert into @Results (TestID, StudentID, Passed) values
(11,2,0),
(11,3,1),(22,3,1),(33,3,1),
(11,4,1);

-- Query
select 
 stu.StudentID, 
 stu.SName, 
 concat(AVG(coalesce(res.Passed,0)*100),'%') as [%Completed]
from @Students as stu
cross join (
    select TestID, TName 
    from @Tests 
    where TestID in (11,22,33)
) as tst
left join @Results as res on (res.StudentID = stu.StudentID and res.TestID = tst.TestID)
group by stu.StudentID, stu.SName;
```

**Result:**

```
StudentID   SName   %Completed
---------   -----   ----------
        1   Ken     0%
        2   Tom     0%
        3   Bob     100%
        4   Jane    33%
```